# Pageview-level Custom Dimensions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters, gtag.js

**The case:** We are running a test on 5% of page views (NOT USERS) with a different ad layout. We are looking to tag each page view that has the different ad layout with a custom dimension.

The custom dimension scope is "Hit".

**The problem we're running into:** Google Analytics reporting is showing more than 5% of page views with the custom dimension. We know (via other reporting) that the different ad layout is only being shown to 5% of traffic (so Google Analytics is overreporting).

I'm assuming this is happening because the dimension we're setting is staying for subsequent page views (i.e. once a user has been tagged with that dimension, all page views after that are tagged). This is almost certainly due to a misunderstanding of how dimensions work and/or the code.

**The code:**

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
    'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'adlayout'}
});
```

Later on in code:

```
gtag('event', 'adlayout_dimension', {'adlayout': 'true'});
```

**Questions:**

- Are custom dimensions the correct way to do this? Is there a better feature for tagging a *page view* in Google Analytics?
- If so, where am I going wrong with my code/setup that's causing it to overreport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is firing after the pageview and the custom dimension is associated with the event.. not the pageview.

To fix it going forward, pass the custom dimension with the pageview itself rather than an event. To do so, edit the tracking code for the relevant pages similar to the following

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID',{
  "dimension1": "true"
});
</script>
```

You can then create a custom report using a flat table, with Page and the Custom Dimension as dimensions together with the desired metrics.

Answer (score -1):

I think that in this case the most suitable scope is at session level. In this way you can see all the sessions that have seen a particular page tagged (obviously if in a session you can see more than one page tagged with your system only the last value will be saved).

Otherwise at hit level but only for specific pages and looking at unique pageviews.

Comment: GA-4 as of April-2022 has no Session scope option for custom dimensions/metrics. Listed as coming-soon feature.

Comment: Thank you, anyway this post is not related to GA4 but Universal Analytics. GA4 is out of topic.

Comment: The code and way the custom event is comprised indicate the question refers to GA4. The question itself is ambiguous but the code is 100% GA4 compatible. Given that universal analytics is not mentioned anywhere I disagree it's out of topic.

Comment: 2 years and 7 months ago GA4 did not exist.

Comment: Untrue, it was available in beta-form mid 2019. And either way the question is ambiguous as to whether they mean UA or GA4. People will likely end up here with searches about either (increasingly GA4 related searches as UA is slated for EOL in 2023). Let's aim to provide useful answers with up-to-date current info yea?